# Replace non-ASCII characters on image upload Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried including the following 2 snippets in functions.php

```
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'remove_accents' );
```

and

```
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'sa_sanitize_spanish_chars', 10);
function sa_sanitize_spanish_chars ($filename) {
return remove_accents( $filename );
}
```

When uploading an image it's supposed to replace french characters like "é" with standard ASCII characters like "e". But it's not working.

I tried inserting the code in 2 different WP install (3.8 and 4.6), but to no avail.

The whole need to replace the characters is because Safari is not able to read URLs with non-ASCII characters in it.

Comment: If you have an answer, please create an answer for it.  Answers get lost when they are edits to questions.

Comment: good point, moved it to answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by Mickaël Gris was the following code which worked on 4.6 and 3.8 as well, just to make sure:

function wpc_sanitize_french_chars($filename) {

```
/* Force the file name in UTF-8 (encoding Windows / OS X / Linux) */
$filemane = mb_convert_encoding($filename, "UTF-8");

$char_not_clean = array('/À/','/Á/','/Â/','/Ã/','/Ä/','/Å/','/Ç/','/È/','/É/','/Ê/','/Ë/','/Ì/','/Í/','/Î/','/Ï/','/Ò/','/Ó/','/Ô/','/Õ/','/Ö/','/Ù/','/Ú/','/Û/','/Ü/','/Ý/','/à/','/á/','/â/','/ã/','/ä/','/å/','/ç/','/è/','/é/','/ê/','/ë/','/ì/','/í/','/î/','/ï/','/ð/','/ò/','/ó/','/ô/','/õ/','/ö/','/ù/','/ú/','/û/','/ü/','/ý/','/ÿ/', '/©/');
$clean = array('a','a','a','a','a','a','c','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','y','a','a','a','a','a','a','c','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','o','o','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u','y','y','copy');

$friendly_filename = preg_replace($char_not_clean, $clean, $filename);


/* After replacement, we destroy the last residues */
$friendly_filename = utf8_decode($friendly_filename);
$friendly_filename = preg_replace('/\?/', '', $friendly_filename);


/* Lowercase */
$friendly_filename = strtolower($friendly_filename);

return $friendly_filename;
```

}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'wpc_sanitize_french_chars', 10);